# How could a log X, Y mouse position on my grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have this script to create grid of rectangles, how would I go about logging map co ordinates of the mouse position so if the mouse was on 1,1 it would log 1,1?:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|0,0|0,1|0,2|0,3|
+---+---+---+---+
|1,0|1,1|1,2|1,3|
+---+---+---+---+
|2,0|2,1|2,2|2,3|
+---+---+---+---+
|3,0|3,1|3,2|3,3|
+---+---+---+---+
```

here is the script I have to create the grid;

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = (32 * 12);
canvas.height = (32 * 12);
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;
var tileSize = 32;

$(document).ready(function(){
    drawGrid();
});

function drawGrid(){
    for(var x = 0; x < 12; x++){
        for(var y = 0; y < 12; y++){
            ctx.rect(posX, posY, tileSize, tileSize);
            ctx.stroke();
            posX += tileSize;
        }
       posY += tileSize;
       posX = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just quantize the mouse position based on the tile size, for example (assuming you have already obtained the mouse position):

```
var gridX = (mouseX / tileSize)|0;
var gridY = (mouseY / tileSize)|0;
```

Now you can log `gridX` and `gridY` as the original grid definition.

Answer (score 0):

On mouse move get the x and y position of the mouse and divide them by the `tileSize`.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/0z0tv3my/4/)

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var mouseX = e.pageX;
  var mouseY = e.pageY;
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = '(' + Math.floor(mouseX / tileSize) + ', ' + Math.floor(mouseY / tileSize) + ')';
}
```